# Why am I having trouble with this simple JOIN in the WHERE selection (using an int)?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT `userlist`.`patient_id` , `results`.`patient_id` , `results`.`result` , `userlist`.`login_id`
FROM `userlist`
JOIN `results` ON `userlist`.`patient_id` = `results`.`patient_id`
WHERE `userlist`.`login_id` = `7555555`
COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

The problem is with the...

```
WHERE `userlist`.`login_id` = `7555555`
```

and I have tried `(7555555)`, `"7555555"` and `'7555555'`.

Missing something, I am stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this without any cotes

```
   WHERE `userlist`.`login_id` = 7555555
```

EDIT:

change the place like that

```
     COLLATE utf8_general_ci
     WHERE `userlist`.`login_id` = 7555555
```

Comment: #1253 - COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'

Comment: then its with collation not integer , integer is right as i told u

Comment: #1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='  //this is after I remove collation

Comment: I found the answer, see my response above. If you can improve on this I will give it to you.

Comment: try replace the place the COLLATE before where clause

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work with....

```
SELECT `userlist`.`patient_id` , `results`.`patient_id` , `results`.`result` , `userlist`.`login_id`
FROM `userlist`
JOIN `results` ON `userlist`.`patient_id` = `results`.`patient_id`
COLLATE utf8_general_ci
WHERE `login_id` =7269715
```

Let me know if this makes sense, otherwise answer an improvement and I will give it to you.